# How to proceed further in this Arithmetico-Geometric Progression problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Question:**
>
> The sum to $n$ terms of the series,
>
> $S=1+5(\frac{4n+1}{4n-3})+9(\frac{4n+1}{4n-3})^2+13(\frac{4n+1}{4n-3})^3+....$

The following image is my approach towards the problem.

[image: Approach]

Could you please tell how to proceed? I proceeded in this way as I did not want to mug-up the complicated formula given for AGP summation.

The final answer is $n(4n-3)$

Comment: Nice work; it has to be an infinite series

Comment: @ganeshie8, Thank you. But in my book it is given to be sum upto n terms only.

Comment: $\cdots$ usually means going to infinity ;) and don't take your textbook too seriously - the author is using the same letter $n$ in the ratio and to count the terms

Comment: @ganeshie8 Are you sure that isn't what he means?

Comment: I'm pretty sure

Comment: @ganeshie8, I considered the summation to infinity and the answer matches. Thank you for your help. But lets see if anyone comes up with finite summation case.

Comment: You must divide your equation by $1-x$, if all is correct.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, If I did so, the expression on the RHS became too complex, so that I stopped with the previous step itself.

Comment: Intellex looks @RobertZ has it with the finite terms. ok not so sure anymore -.-

Comment: @ganeshie8, Thanks for spending your time sir. Doubt got cleared by RobertZ. Interestingly, in this problem the value of summation is same whether it is finite or infinite. Need to think more on this stuff. This is what makes mathematics interesting.!!!!

Comment: Totally agreeXD for now $\dfrac{4n+1}{4n-3}$ looks like a magic ratio that makes any partial sum equal to $n(4n-3)$. Infinite sum seems to diverge...

Comment: @ganeshie8   Yes. What do you mean by infinite sum seems to diverge?

Comment: @ganeshie8 : Of course it diverges, $\sum (1+4k)x^k$ is combination of geometric and binomial series which has radius of convergence $|x|<1$. But $\frac{4n+1}{4n-3}>1$, so it is outside of the region of convergence.

Comment: @LutzL ahh right in that sum notation using $k$ for the index it's easy to see the sum diverges haha. Ty:)

Comment: @Intellex diverges means the infinite sum doesn't converge. For example $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\cdots$ converges to $2$. But $1+2+3+4+\cdots$ diverges to $\infty$. If it seems circular, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivergentSeries.html

Comment: @ganeshie8, Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is correct!
Now for $x=\frac{4n+1}{4n-3}$, we find that
$$S_n=\frac{x^n((4n-3)x-(4n+1))+(3x-1)}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{0+(3x-1)}{(x-1)^2}=n(4n-3).$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$x=1+\frac {4}{4n-3}$$ so $$1-x=\frac {-4}{4n-3}$$

Substitute in  your last line and you will get the $$s_n=n(4n-3)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir.

Comment: Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1):

By your work
$$S=\frac{1}{1-x}-4\frac{x(x^{n+1}-1)}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{(4n-3)x^n}{1-x}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir.

Comment: This was only your work!

Comment: Yes sir. I didn't know how to proceed which I learnt in the accepted answer. I thanked you for spending your time in trying to clarifying my doubt.

Comment: It was just a simple substitution which would have made the steps easier.